# NET Core Ok() return json formatted as string in Angular

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core

From .NET Core I return object in `Ok()` in method with `IActionResult` result:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadJsonFiles()
{
      return Ok(new { status = "Ok", message = "" });
}
```

In Angular I have that json but it is formatted as string. I don't have object with property status and message, only string:

```
this.uploader.response.subscribe(res => {
..

res = "{"status":"Ok","message":""}"
```

In Startup I have set formatters for controllers:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
})
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Angular's HttpClient return an object instead of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015175/how-to-have-angulars-httpclient-return-an-object-instead-of-a-string)

Comment: Not exaclty, because why my api return string when I use Ok(), it should return json to the Angular service, I have set formatters in Startup. Maybe I should have another one?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, have you taken a look in Developer Tools -> Network tab? There you can examine what is sent from the browser and received from the server. (If you are not using Chrome you can download Fiddler which will let you trace the rest calls.) Take a look the body of your response. Is it a string? Take a look at the `accept` header in your request. It should say `application/json`. Take a look at `Content-Type` header in the response. It should also say `application/json`

Comment: Following mortb's comment, you can specify the response type is json by using `[Produces("application/json")]` attribute on the method.

Comment: As far as I know, the OK result will return json result by default. I suggest you could try to use `return Json(new { status = "Ok", message = "saaaaaa" });` and try again.